# Changing colors in a protovis node-link tree

Tags: protovis

I'm new to Protovis although it is no longer under development and D3 is the newer software. However, I'm using the Node-Link Tree from Protovis to display my data for various reasons, so I prefer to stick to Protovis however if anyone has an R package in mind that I haven't come across yet (other than dendextend, ggplot2, d3network, etc) to get me to use R instead of Protovis please let me know. Anyhow, a snippet of my data for Protovis looks like this:

```
var PB = {
    PBC03013: {
"103937011_PbUn_2838": 3013,
"103934808_PbUn_26206": 3013,
"103930675_PbUn_35145": 3013,
"103941984_PbUn_52102": 3013,
"103935933_PbUn_63128": 3013,
"103966210_PbUn_64271": 3013
},
PBC03018: {
"103935981_PbUn_53113": 3018,
"103934997_PbUn_59093": 3018,
"103936640_PbUn_65330": 3018,
"103955166_PbUn_112582": 3018
},
...
}
}
I'm trying to change the node colors such that the dots for the elements in PB03013 and PB03018 are different, say "green" and "red", respectively. So all of the PB03013 element dots are green and all of the PB03018 element dots are red. There are 10 nodes in total. I've done a lot of research on this but I'm having such a hard time setting different dot colors I decided to post for help.  

This is the body of my html code:
var tree = vis.add(pv.Layout.Tree)
    .nodes(pv.dom(PB).root("PB").nodes())
    .depth(127)
    .breadth(7.25)
    .orient("radial");

tree.link.add(pv.Line);

tree.node.add(pv.Dot)
    .fillStyle(function(n) n.firstChild ? "#a1d99b" : "#de2d26");

tree.label.add(pv.Label);

So far, I've been using pv.Color pallets or n.key n.parentNode, etc code alterations to no success. I also set a new variable to force different colors like:
var re = "",
    color = pv.Colors.category19().by(function(d) d.parentNode.nodeName)
    nodes = pv.dom(PB).root("PB").nodes();

Then:

treemap.leaf.add(pv.Panel)
    .fillStyle(function(d) color(d).alpha(title(d).match(re) ? 1 : .2))

The node-link tree code can also be found here: 
http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/tree.html  

Any help is greatly appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

[`networkD3`](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3) is the successor to `d3Network` and is much more capable and may suit your needs. In particular, the current dev version (v0.4.9000 as of 2017.09.06) has a new `treeNetwork` function that is very capable, including the ability to explicitly set the color of each individual node and link. We'd be happy to get [feedback](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues) as it's still in development.